# Retrieve all languages used by a Github user

Tags: php, html, json, github, github-api

In my script I have a function that retrieves JSON information from the Github API, https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos.

I want to have a different function to get all the languages used by (in this case) octocat and then count how many times he used the language.

I was thinking of this:

```
        foreach($json['language'] as $RepoLanguage) 
        {
            echo $RepoLanguage;
        }
```

but that won't work, any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: What are you getting when you say it won't work? Does it output anything?

Comment: try `$json[0]['language']` instead

Comment: It will only output: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Can you post more of your code? The code you use to populate `$json` in particular.

Comment: there isn't much more code to post. there's just the cURL function to retrieve the JSON and the `json_decode()`, which I checked by doing `echo $json[0]['language'];`. That does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main reason is that you did not specify the User Agent as specified here: https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required

Did you check what **result** you have in the `$json?`

Here's a working example.

```
<?php
    function get_content_from_github($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'My User Agent');
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $content;
    }

    $json = json_decode(get_content_from_github('https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos'), true);

    foreach($json as $repo) {
        $language = $repo['language'];
    }
?>
```